# überlöten - exact meaning?

Tags: meaning, verb

I am helping out a heritage craft charity and they wanted me to look at a manual written in German.  I am having problems with one sentence.  It says, “Spleißstellen dürfen nicht überlötet werden.”  Does this mean

1. splices must not be soldered (at all) or
2. splices must not be soldered excessively?

If you could also tell me how confident you are in  your answer that would be great.

Comment: For a really reliable answer you should give more context. It might depend simply on the field of application if *überlöten* should be understood as *solder over* or as *solder too much* (although *solder too much* would be very rare; but you never know if you don't see the exact field of technology). E.g. various elements of electronics such as resistors or capacitors can get destroyed by too much heat, and when they are close to a splice, soldering the splice *too much* would do them harm.

Comment: Please note there is a third translation for "überlöten" thinkable: To solder something again which has been soldered already in the past. So as @ChristianGeiselmann already stated it is important to know what kind of splices are you talking about.

Comment: @Thomas  Even more meanings are possible. Szene aus der Ganovenwelt: *"Der Kleine wird frech. Ich glaube, dem müssen wir mal eins überlöten."* (Ihn schlagen, insbesondere auf den Kopf.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Ich kenne nur überbraten. ;-)

Comment: The context is wire splicing for vintage aircraft.  The immediate near sentences: “Spleißstellen dürfen nicht überlötet werden, Weil einmal hierdurch jede Elastizität beseitigt, die Hanfseele entweder verbrannt, zumindest aber mit Lötpaste usw. durchsetzt wird.  Neben der Bruchgefahr durch Ausglühen und Abbrechen, besteht dann noch die Möglichkeit des Durchrostens.  Richtig ist es, den Spleiß mit Wickellitze abzuwickeln...  Dadurch wird verhindert, daß das Ende des Spleißes aufgehen kann und daß man sich an den abgezwickten Drahten verletzt.”

Comment: Sorry, that should say “an den abgezwickten Drahtenden verletzt”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure that "überlöten" means your first proposal:

> Splices must not be soldered at all.

"Überlöten" means "löten über" that is "solder over". This is the same meaning as in "übermalen" (paint over) oder in "überkleben" (paste over, stick over).

As [Janka](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/23885/janka) mentioned in the comments, your second proposal "to solder excessively" would be "**zer**löten". Or this meaning would be described in a manual as "nicht zu stark löten" or "nur leicht löten" or something similar.

Comment: *To solder excessively* would be ***zer**löten*, in contrast to the usual ***ver**löten*.